# Evaluate integral $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{x}{\sin(x)+6x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Show that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac x {\sin(x)+6x} \, dx =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}\ln \left( \cot \frac \pi 8 \right)$$

I tried to apply a related theory for the integral using substitution for $x,$ since there is 0 as the lower interval,  $x=\frac\pi2-x $

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\frac\pi2-x}{\sin(\frac\pi2-x)+6(\frac\pi2-x)} \, dx$$

But what to do next? Is there a specific substitution when there is a denominator with trigonometric and algebraic function together?

Comment: maybe there is a typo, from the looks of it I am not sure there is an easy way to get an elementary function out of this

Comment: I know this is bad, but I checked with wolfram alpha. The integral,  numerically, is about $0.2286$ while your right-hand side is about $0.9789$

Comment: Even I checked it on wolfram alpha,I thought it was due to radian degree issue... When i fed this integral into scientific calculator(FX-991ES+) it gave a Math Error! This is even confusing.. I got this question form a school test paper. So there is a chance of error. Anyway I'm keen to know what substitution to use when we get a denominator like this. Thanks.

Comment: @emil I'll still see if I can integrate it. Regardless, it looks to be kind of an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq \sin(x)\leq x$ for any $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin(x)+6x}\,dx \in \left[\frac{\pi}{14},\frac{\pi^2}{12\pi+4}\right]$$
while $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\log\cot\frac{\pi}{8}$ is approximately $1$.
 There must have been a typo since the RHS is approximately four times larger than the LHS.